# How to get all data for a record from table with data from another table

Tags: laravel-5

I have a table called reservations, and it contains room_id and person_id 
i want to to make something like this

```
Reservation::find($id)->with(['person','room'])->get()
```

so it will return the all reservation info with that id , with person info and room info

any help ?

Comment: are you trying to join two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return Reservation::with("The table that contains the id")->find(id of record that looking for);
```